# Is a small demo a good idea for an interview?

Tags: interview, pointers

Unfortunately most of my work is internal -- I was toying with the idea of a small web demo to give the company better insight.  What do you think?

Comment: If the company wants demo they will ask you for it.

Comment: Think about how badly it'll look if the demo (somehow) failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a website for yourself to showcase your abilities. Include it on your resume and business card (if you have one). Let it be your living demo.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea. Mention on your CV that they can view your work online. During the interview, **ask first** before giving a demo. Giving a demo when your interviewer is not interested in seeing it will be annoying and you will loose a few points

Comment: @DPB - I sort of disagree you would lose points.  It really has to do with the interviewer I suppose.  If the demo was trivial thing it might really impress them.

Comment: You might lose points if the demo *fails* to impress them...

Comment: @Ramhound:  Having a demo ready to go is probably a plus.  Asking if the interviewer wants to see it won't hurt you.  Taking control of the interview is almost always a bad idea.